# Vim phpcomplete (omnifunc) doesn't work, detects error while processing function phpcomplete#CompletePHP

Tags: vim, ide

while writing PHP, when I press (C-X) + (C-O) for auto completion this is the error I get

```
Error detected while processing function phpcomplete#CompletePHP[131]..function phpcomplete#CompletePHP[63]..phpcomplete#GetCurrentName
Space:
```

and when I retry pressing the keys this is the error I get

```
E565: Not allowed to change text or change window
```

and I can't reproduce the first error ("Error detected while processing...") unless I close vim and reopen it.

my .vimrc config is the following:

```
 syntax on
  call plug#begin()
  Plug 'rust-lang/rust.vim'
  Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
  Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
  Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'
  call plug#end()
  set background=dark
  set t_Co=256
  set cmdheight=4
  let g:ale_completion_enabled = 1
  let g:ale_linters = {'rust': ['analyzer']}
  let g:ale_sign_column_always = 1
  let g:ale_fixers = { 'rust': ['rustfmt', 'trim_whitespace', 'remove_trailing_l  ines'] }
  let g:rustfmt_autosave = 1
  :set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
  :set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
  :set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
  :set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
```

I use it for Rust, PHP and front end. **autocompletion works well and smoothly for HTML, CSS and Javascript** but not for PHP.

I'm on Debian 11 (Bullseye) and my vim version is 8.2.2434

thanks in advance :)

Comment: First of all, you have many things going on at the same time. Ale, YouCompleteMe, manually setting `omnifunc`. In fact, you're overriding your settings for omnifunc at the end of your file. There is no need to call custom completion functions in that way since ftplugins will override that option for you. Delete the last lines and then start debugging as usual: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/210

Comment: thanks @r_31415, the six lines from call plug#begin() to call plug#end() were causing the issue, I don't know why, I deleted the vimrc lines one by one and then when I reached there the error was solved, I rewrote the whole .vimrc again just without these lines and the issue was solved! it's weird but it was solved :) thank you!

Comment: The six lines you're talking about were your plugins, right? so you rewrote your vimrc without plugins?

Comment: Yes, @r_31415 without the plugins but the problem isn't with plugins, if I remove the lines related to each individual plugin the issue isn't solved, even if I remove the lines related to all of the plugins still the issue isn't solved but when I remove the two "call plug#begin()" and "call plug#end()" lines (where there is nothing between them) then omnifunc does it's job right

Comment: That's certainly weird! I don't know what could be causing that behavior. Well, I'm glad you vimrc is working now :)

Comment: I'm also confused xD, thanks for your efforts @r_31415, if I found anything new related to this I'll update